# Getting authentication error while creating Postgres db

Tags: python, postgresql, macos

Getting authentication error while creating Postgres db

```sh
bash-3.2$ createdb blog_api_db
Password: 
Password: 
createdb: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "vish"
```

login as postgres user works:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
Password:
Password for user postgres:
psql (13.2) Type "help" for help.
postgres=#
```

`pg_hba.conf` contents:

```
local all postgres peer
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all   all                 trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all   all   127.0.0.1/32  trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all   all   ::1/128       trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                       trust
host    replication     all       127.0.0.1/32    trust
host    replication     all       ::1/128         trust
```

Comment: Hi, could you please add more information about your database cluster?  Did you actually set the password yet?  Are you able to log in to the database by some other means?  What does your `pg_hba.conf` file look like?

Comment: Hello,
I'm new to Postgres and I tried below command and this works for me. Im able to switch to Postgres
sudo -u postgres psql
Password:
Password for user postgres: 
psql (13.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#

Comment: This is how my pg_hba.conf file looks like:
``local all postgres peer
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local  all  all  trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all   all  127.0.0.1/32  trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all all ::1/128  trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all      trust
host    replication     all      127.0.0.1/32    trust
host    replication     all       ::1/128            trust``

Comment: That's strange -- you don't have any entries in `pg_hba.conf` with `password` authentication -- you only have entries with `trust` and one with `peer`.  In either case, i think you might be better off creating the database as `postgres` user and/or log in as `postgres` and change the password for `vish` with `ALTER ROLE vish WITH PASSWORD '<yourpassword>';`

Comment: You will probably have to login as the postgres user with psql  and create a new user (role) for vish, and grant that user create db privilege. Commands such as `createdb` will try to connect to the postgresql host using the same username as your current shell session (`whoami`). You could also run createdb as the postgres user.

Comment: Hello,
I tried ALTER ROLE vish WITH PASSWORD '<yourpassword>'; 
Later I ran into access issue so used the below command
alter user vish createdb;
After running these two commands im able to create the db.

Thanks guys for all the help